# Integrating an ODE in terms of elliptic functions

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, complex-integration, nonlinear-system, elliptic-functions

Consider the ODE for $w:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$
\begin{align}
w''=2w^3+Aw+B &&(1)
\end{align}
We can multiply it by $w'$ and then integrate to get
\begin{align}
w'^2=w^4+Aw^2+2Bw+C &&(2)
\end{align}
($A,B,C$ are complex constants)

My question is how would one then integrate (2) - i.e. obtain an explicit expression for the solution $w$?

In particular, equation (1) is found in `Ordinary Differential Equations' by Ince. It's listed as equation VIII in section 14.316. Ince states that it is "integrable in terms of elliptic functions".
Unfortunately, I cannot see how this would be done.

As an example of what I'm looking for, in a problem related to the one above, one is able to transform the ODE
\begin{align}
P'^2-P^4+\lambda P^2+\frac{B^2}{P^2}+2A=0 && (3)
\end{align}
into the ODE defining the Weierstrass elliptic function
$$\wp'^2=4\wp^3-g_2\wp-g_3$$
by taking 
$$\wp(x):=P(x)^2-\frac{\lambda}{3},$$
where $g_2, g_3$ are constants depending on $A,B,\lambda$.
And so the general solution to (3) is
$$P(x)=\pm\sqrt{\wp(x)+\frac{\lambda}{3}}$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equation is
$$(w')^2 = (w - w_0) P(w),
\quad \deg P = 3.$$
Let $w = 1/\zeta + w_0$, then
$$(\zeta')^2 = \zeta^3 P {\left( \frac 1 \zeta + w_0 \right)} = Q(\zeta),
\quad \deg Q = 3.$$
If we eliminate the $\zeta^2$ term with
$$\zeta = \frac {4 \wp - \frac 1 3 [\zeta^2] Q(\zeta)} {[\zeta^3] Q(\zeta)}$$
and reduce the coefficients modulo $w_0^4 + A w_0^2 + 2 B w_0 + C$ (treating $w_0$ as a variable), we get
$$(\wp')^2 =
4 \wp^3 - \frac {A^2 + 12 C} {12} \wp +
 \frac {A^3 + 54 B^2 - 36 A C} {216}.$$

Comment: very nice, thankyou. The bounty is yours!
But sadly even this approach does not seem to be totally general. For instance, $Q$ could fail to be a cubic polynomial, the most trivial example of which is when $w'^2=w^4$, forcing $w_0=0$ and $P(w)=w^3$, and $Q(\zeta):=\zeta^3 P(\frac{1}{\zeta}+w_0)=1$.
At this point I am fairly convinced that while a totally general solution to my ODE in terms of $\wp$ exists, this general solution is not something that will be easily written down.

Comment: $\deg Q = 3$ if $P(w_0) \neq 0$. Otherwise
$$z = \int \frac {d\zeta} {\sqrt {Q(\zeta)}}$$
gives an elementary $\zeta(z)$.

Comment: ah yes I see. And we can always choose $w_0$ and $P$ such that $P(w_0)\neq 0$ so long as $w^4+Aw^2+2Bw+C$  has at least three distinct roots. 

In the case where it has two distinct roots, we only run into trouble in the subcase $(w-a)^2(w-b)^2$. But then by Vieta and the vanishing cubic coefficient we must have $a=-b$ so the quartic has no $w$ term we get back the ODE for Jacobi elliptic functions.
In the case where there's only one root, this root must be $0$ by Vieta which means we must have the simple case $w'^2=w^4$.